# Error 8000 (AtlasError): '(Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, studio3t

I connected to my Cluster (MongoDB Atlas) using Studio 3T. But when i click on the users button, i receive the error of the photo. I have the user ailtonjr with atlasAdmin@admin role in the Database Access and my IP in Network Access. I can delete and create databases normally on the Atlas via browser, but can't on Studio 3T. [image: Error 8000]

Answer (score 1):

`atlasAdmin` is a custom role which does not include many "admin" privileges as you'd expect. MongoDB's team [choose](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-8676) to leave this ambiguous on purpose so it's unclear exactly what this role contains.

The reason you can do all those actions via their GUI is because you are connected under a different role there, it's not a direct db connection. They do not allow full access for manually created users, I suspect as it can cause synchronization issues.

What you can do is give your user the `dbAdmin` privilege through their GUI, this will allow you to create and drop databases.

Comment: I updated the role of my user to: Built-in Role: Atlas Admin. Custom role: dbManager (Global actions and roles). Specific Privileges: readWriteAnyDatabase, dbAdminAnyDatabase. Still getting the error.

Comment: I just personally tested it and it works for me, make sure you're updating the right user and are executing a viable action